# Vertical-align inline, again

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I know there are a lot of articles outside and I know most techniques about vertical, but I can't get why this works that way:

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.one {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.two {
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="one">Textx</span>
  <span class="two">-</span>
</p>
```

Question is: middle of my .two element is middle of what? Do I always need to set vertical-align for first element in a row to get this to work properly?
Thanks.

Comment: you have different font-size and .. and character whic is not a letter, you can also reset vertical-align with em values , https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BOKXVp ( not too sure of visual alignement you where looking for ) defaut value is baseline.

Comment: [This book](http://css-live.ru/articles/obzor-inlajnovyj-kontekst-formatirovaniya.html) can help you better understand inline formatting context. Sadly, it's only available in Russian - but I hope you'll be able to read it, judging by your profile name.

Comment: Thanks fen1x for book!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `vertical-align: middle;` aligns the **middle point of the element** by `parent's baseline + 1/2 parent's height`

In your case, the first `span` is being aligned by `baseline`, so you don't see any effect of the second `span` alignment. So here you need to specify the `vertical-align: middle;` for the first span. But if you want to align the `.two` , for instance, by `top` the first span does not require to specify `vertical-align`.

Alternatively you may use `flex-box` to align you spans:

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* if you suppose multiline content */
}

.one {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.two {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="one">Textx</span>
  <span class="two">-</span>
</p>
```

**Why middle doesn't work without first element alignment**

Actually it does. First, let's understand how the middle works in general. It takes the font-size of the parent's element, base line of this text, 1/2 (half) of the text's height and aligns the element by the calculated point.

In you case parent element is `p` and it's `font-size` is 16px (here at least). The first span has `font-size: 50px`. You are waiting that the second span will be align based on the first's span font-size (50px) but actually it is being aligned by the parent's `16px`. And as the first span is align by baseline (by default) you don't see any effect for the `.two`. To illustrate what's going on, let's try to add a text between the spans

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.one {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.two {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="one">Textx</span>
  xxx 
  <span class="two">-</span>
</p>
```

You can see that the second span is actually aligned by the middle of the common text.

So the rule is pretty simple. If you'd like to align all inline elements by the middle, you have to add `vertical-align: middle` to each the element.

Also you may use `table-cell` on parent's element (it works a bit different and aligns all inline elements inside) or `flex-box` as I showed above.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but with that said "Basically, vertical-align: middle; aligns the middle point of the element by parent's baseline + 1/2 parent's height" my .two element can't be on base line, because you say about 1/2 parent's height.

Comment: Maybe I don't undertand it right, can you explain please what does it mean 1/2 parent's height, how to see and understand it? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got you simple rule - for every element. I asked about this, because almost always I'm facing troubles with this property, especially working on PixelPerfect layout and working with typo in that case is the hardest part.